# Question about application of momentum conservation in Circular motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum

The given question says , Two smalls discs A and B of masses m1 and M2 connected by a light inextensible string of length l are placed on a frictionless horizontal floor. Disc A is held at rest and the disc B is projected to move around the disc A with a constant speed u on a circular path. If the disc A is now released, the disc b will move on a path as shown. Find p and q. Now I was having some conceptual clarity in this area, for example according to me A should gain an initial velocity along the string as the force which was holding A in position is removed hence the tension force will act on it, now after some time when it gains a velocity there will be no net force in the system and so we can apply momenttum conservation, I was not sure how to apply it though, for example I'm not sure if B will move a circular path with respect to A and also that how will we apply momentum conservation and solve this . Any help is appreciated[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will be solved with center of mass and not momentum

Comment: Hint, for p the block B has moved a distance 2pil wrt to A, so you can calculate the time from that and as center of mass has a constant velocity you can equate these two to get the answers